# Pandas Dataframe : Why is there a difference between df.loc[df['height']>3,'height'] = 2 and df.loc[df['height']>3,['height']] = 2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, set, variable-assignment

I have a pandas dataframe named df which has several columns, one of these is called 'height'. I want to modify heights higher than 3 and replace them by 2. I used this code :

```
df.loc[df['height']>3,'height'] = 2
```

this does not make any modification.

I use this code :

```
df.loc[df['height']>3,['height']] = 2
```

this works perfectly fine. I sort of understand that in the first version, a copy version of df was created but, it is not clear why, and I fine weird to have the [] make such a change.

Could someone explain what is happening ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you didn't provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so trying to help you becomes a guessing game:

Assuming you have a simple dataframe like

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'height':range(6)})
```

then both your code lines work perfectly fine, except that the additional indexing operator [ ] in the second version is completely unnecessary and that there is no `copy version of df` involved in neither case.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer and the advice. Hmm, it seems like I was looking at the unupdated version of df. It looks like Spyder does not update variable in variable explorer. So sorry for this question. I guess I should remove it.